# How can I optimize my code so my Google Colab doens't crash

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, data-science, google-colaboratory

I ran into a issue where Google Colab's ram is running out. I use the free version and I'm not sure if it's because it can't handle or if my code is very bad optimized. As I'm new to the field I believe my code is very slow and badly optimized. Wanted to ask a bit of help as I'm still learning.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

df = pd.read_csv('path/beforeNeural.csv')
df.shape
df.head()

df.isnull().sum()

encoder = LabelEncoder()

df['Property Type'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Property Type'])
df['Old/New'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Old/New'])
df['Record Status - monthly file only'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Record Status - monthly file only'])
df['PPDCategory Type'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['PPDCategory Type'])
df['County'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['County'])
df['District'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['District'])
df['Town/City'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Town/City'])
df['Duration'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Duration'])
df['Transaction unique identifier'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Transaction unique identifier'])
df['Date of Transfer'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Date of Transfer'])

X = df.drop(columns='Price', axis=1)
Y = df['Price']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

df.shape

boostenc = XGBRegressor()

boostenc.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: What is the size of your `path/beforeNeural.csv`?

Comment: 22m, is that too much?

Comment: I assume you're meaning MB, so yes its an ok size

Comment: Hmm no it's actually 2.3GB, that 22m was 22 million rows of data, sorry for miss information. Is that a too much? Should I get Colab Pro or other better free Cloud Computing?

Comment: (1) Where is your file located? (2) what is the data you have inside of it? (3) upon crashing or before, do you get any warnings or errors? (4) After how much time does it crash?

Comment: 1- Now it's on my google drive 2-sorry didn't understand but Its text, int and date time 3- no just warning for running out of Ram 4- about 3 mins

Comment: So your data is just text and DateTime?

Comment: Yes, I ran some more times with the csv files on the runtime content file, removed all google drive needed library and after applying the other person's changes it normally crashes here: 
"X_concat = pd.DataFrame(X_concat.toarray(), columns = encoder.get_feature_names(categorical_columns))
"

Comment: The other person is still me from what I see lol, anyway I added a little change to my code using `Sparse`, please check it and let me know (in my answer code you have approach 1 and approach 2, use one or the other)

Comment: I tried and it did nothing... But thank's anyways, I already learned some stuff

Comment: Still the same crash? do you get any warning or error upon the crash? if so please paste it here and I'll try to add some more and get an acceptable answer for you :)

Comment: No, Ram just runs out and Google Colab craches because of that, Thank's anyways, already learned new stuff ;)

Comment: also by the way on colab, you can use the `wget` command in order to load the dataset, it's good for big datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try, here is a possible option to optimize your code,

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

df = pd.read_csv('path/beforeNeural.csv')

categorical_columns = ['Property Type', 'Old/New', 'Record Status - monthly file only', 'PPDCategory Type', 'County', 'District', 'Town/City', 'Duration', 'Transaction unique identifier', 'Date of Transfer']
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
X_concat = encoder.fit_transform(df[categorical_columns])
# Approach 1:
X_concat = pd.DataFrame(X_concat.toarray(), columns = encoder.get_feature_names(categorical_columns))
# Approach 2:
X_concat = pd.SparseDataFrame(X_concat.to_coo(), columns = encoder.get_feature_names(categorical_columns))

X_numerical = df.drop(columns = categorical_columns + ['Price'])
X = pd.concat([X_numerical, X_concat], axis = 1)
Y = df['Price']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 2)

boostenc = XGBRegressor()
boostenc.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

> Note, I removed the unused imports and deleted the calls such as
> `df.head()` for example in the middle of the code, which does nothing and also
> does not print anything when you use it like that in the middle of the
> code

### Code Explanation:

1. Instead of using `LabelEncoder`, I used `OneHotEncoder` in order to one-hot-encode all of the categorical features.
   This creates a new binary column for each unique value in the categorical features.
   In general, one-hot-encoding is usually a better approach to handle categorical features when using machine learning other than just assigning the integer values using the `LabelEncoder`.
2. I extracted the names of all of the categorical columns into a list, that way it's easier to modify them when it's needed.

Comment: Very good, it took a good while to crash this time but still crashed, thanks thought for the tips.

Comment: @SamirAlmeida did you get any errors or something?

Comment: No it was just Ram running out. Already commented above but will repeat, is a 2.3GB file too much?